# Why is one function of divisor >3000% faster than the other?

Tags: python, function, performance, time

I was doing some simple Python exercises on https://www.practicepython.org/ when I did this task https://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/02/26/04-divisors.html.

I wanted to test different ways to code the answer, and I saw solutions in the comment field that piqued my interest; two codes looked similar, but one is almost 4000% faster than the other!

**Code:**

```
import time

start = time.time()

print("Fast code:")

#the slow code
def divisor(x):
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, int(x)):
        if x % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
            divisors.sort()
    print(divisors)


divisor(50000000)
end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: ")
print(end - start)

print("Fast code:")

start = time.time()

#the fast code!
def divisor2(x):
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, int(x**.5)):
        if x % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
            divisors.append(x//i)
            divisors.sort()
    print(divisors)
divisor2(50000000)
end = time.time()
print("Time elapsed: ")
print(end - start)
```

**Time elapsed (slow code):**

```
3.1739981174468994
```

**Time elapsed (fast code):**

```
0.0010004043579101562
```

Can anyone please tell me how this is possible so perhaps anyone can take home some valuable faster coding skills for their toolbelt?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `x` and `square root of x`?

Comment: Both versions are also slower than necessary because they sort in every loop iteration. It would be better if they only sorted at the end.

Comment: For starters, in one, you iterate until `x`, and for another, you iterate until `int(x**0.5)`... for a number like `50000000`, so the first does `50000000` iterations, while the second does `7071` iterations...

Comment: Both functions are also "broken" - they should each increment the range end by 1 and use a set instead of a list. Try with ``16`` and you'll get ``[1, 2, 4, 8]`` and ``[1, 2, 8, 16]`` respectively. With my suggested fix they both yield ``[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]`` (after sorting the set once).

Comment: @MikeScotty why a set? for `divisors`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, for divisors, otherwise ``4`` will show up twice for ``16``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x**.5` is x to the power of a half, it's a square root.

Both using `x = 50,000,000`, the first does:

```
for i in range(1, int(x)):
```

*fifty million loops*.

The second does:

```
for i in range(1, int(x**.5)):
```

*seven thousand loops*.

The reason you can do this when calculating divisors is because they form two sides of a rectangle:

```
 __
|  |
|  |
|__|
```

If you know the area (the goal, 50 million), and you know one side (the counter `i`) then you can work out the other side. Where both sides are the same is the square root, and it acts like a pivot, if one is shorter than that then the other must be longer, and balance it out. That is, `100/2 = 50` that gives you both 2 and 50.

So you can count up to the square root to find all the short answers, work out the other side (the counter-balance) for each one, and then you have all the answers. `100/10 = 10` that gives you 10 as a divisor, and tells you that if you keep counting up to get to `100/50 = 2` you've already seen that from the other side and got 50.

That's why the second code has:

```
        divisors.append(i)
        divisors.append(x//i)
```

Adding two values to the list, after only testing one.

Comment: Very good and simple explanation. I appreciate this.
Thank you, TessellatingHeckler!

Answer (score 2):

Classic O(n) vs O(n^0.5)

The first one is doing 50000000 operations

The second one is doing 7000 operations (7000 times fewer)

And what about the time difference? 3000 times faster? Something doesn't add up.

Here!

```
divisors.sort()
```

You're doing this after each divisor pair is found, and that's an expensive operation. Simply shift it 2 indentation levels to the left (same level as `print`), and see the ~7000 times faster performance or more.

Why this is happening?

Well, if you found that 15 is divisible by 3, then why check every other number and then check 5 again, when you know that if 15 is divisible by 3, it's also divisible by 15/3. Also no number is divisible by any number bigger than its square root, where the result is also bigger than the square root. Thus, it doesn't make sense to run the loop for so long - it will find no solutions. Since 50000000 is definitely not divisible by any number bigger than 7071.067811865475 which will result in another number bigger than 7071.067811865475, checking 7072 and bigger numbers is a huge waste of time, if we add the result of the division for each divisor we find.

Comment: I think the way this is worded could be confusing. There are definitely numbers that divide the input that are bigger than the square root. The issue is that we've already found them because we add both `i` and `x // i` to the list, so there's no need to check beyond the square root.

Comment: yeah - no number is equal to the product of two numbers greater than the square root. but 50000000 is divisible by 25000000 >> 7000.

Comment: I did try the 2 indent to left (with print) for the .sort() method. This did nothing on the process time on my PyCharm. Not even when I tested on higher divisor. I tried 5000000000000 with no change. 
Original:
            divisors.sort()
    print(divisors)
Time elapsed: 
0.16904497146606445
 2 indent to left:
    divisors.sort()
    print(divisors)
Time elapsed: 
0.17499947547912598

I tried several times and they seemed to be even on time.
Perhaps some crazy high number, but I do not see the value of changing position of .sort().

Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed. I overestimated the number of sorts it will do (the number of divisors it has). Why the ratio isn't 1:7000 and just 1:3000 is an interesting curiosity.